# how to append image with text from mysqldatabase in android

Tags: android

here my Main.java code

```
enter code here
JSONArray json = jArray.getJSONArray("names");
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
         adapter=new ImageAdapter(this, json);
         list.setAdapter(adapter);
here my imageadapter.java code
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Bitmap bmp;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
private ImageView[] mImages;
String[] itemimage;
 TextView[] tv;
String itemname;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
      this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];
      String qrimage;
      try
     {
      for (int i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
          qrimage = image.getString("itemimage");
          itemname=image.getString("itemname");
          System.out.println(itemname);

          byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

          bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes,
                                              0,
                                              qrimageBytes.length);
          mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
         mImages[i].setImageBitmap(bmp);
          mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
      }

      }catch (Exception e) {
// TODO: handle exception
      }
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImages.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return mImages[position];


}

}
   Main.xml code
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />

    </LinearLayout>
```

the above code i can view the images in list view now i want add text view into the each image . also the image size should be reduce and get item name is besides the image view
can please any send the sample piece of code for me

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display the images from mysqldatabase to android in listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857773/how-to-display-the-images-from-mysqldatabase-to-android-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

You should go for Customized rows in the Listview. You should create a customized row.xml in the res\layout folder. Use this customized in the getView(..,..,..) method in the Adapter. Please check the link [http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html][1]

[1]: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html for more information. Here in the getView, you returned Images. So you are getting the Listview with Images. Instaed of that you should inflate the XML row.xml and set Image to Imageview and set the Text to TextView.

Please check the link for more information.

Listview is also having the option to deal with more than one design for rows.

Comment: how can i wrote the code in base adapter class. i can view database images in listview use base adapter like this i want view text besides of image please tell me

Comment: In getView method try the code. LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(Activity.this);ll.aad(ImageViewObject);ll.add(TextViewObject);return ll;